# Counting triangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

[image: The Figure]

I got a question yesterday, to count the number of triangles in the above figure. I counted them, then thought about a formula to do the counting. I can't do that. Can someone show me how?

Comment: `I counted them` It helped if you posted how you did that, since by the time you got it right for $n=5$ the formula should become apparent.

Comment: maybe $$5\times(5+4+3+2+1)=75$$

Comment: @dxiv I just counted the normal way, but got 69. Must be wrong, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its rather easy, once you think about it.

Let $h$ be the number of horizontal lines, and $v$ the number of non-horizontal lines. To form a triangle, you need to choose two non-horizontal lines, and one horizontal as base.

You can choose non-horizontal lines in $^v\text C_2={{v(v-1)}\over{2}}$ ways. Any of the horizontal lines may be selected in $^h\text C_1=h$ ways.

So, the total number of triangles is ${{^v\text C_2}\cdot{^h\text C_1}}$

Which is ${{{v(v-1)}\over{2}}\cdot{h}}$

And thus

$${{hv(v-1)}\over{2}}$$

P.S. In your figure, it is ${{5×6×5}\over2}=75$